# Unexpected behavior in subsetting aggregate function in R

Tags: r, logic, aggregate, subset

I have a data frame that contains with the following format:

```
manufacturers pricegroup leads
harley        <2500      #
honda         <5000      #
...           ...        ..
```

I am using the aggregate function to pull out data in the following way:

```
aggregate( leads ~ manufacturer + pricegroup, data=leaddata, 
    FUN=sum, subset=(manufacturer==c("honda","harley")))
```

I noticed this is not returning the correct totals.  The numbers for each manufacturer get smaller and smaller the more manufacturers I add to the subset group.  However, if I use:

```
aggregate( leads ~ manufacturer + pricegroup, data=leaddata, 
    FUN=sum, subset=(manufacturer=="honda" | manufacturer=="harley"))
```

It returns the correct numbers.  For the life of me, I can't figure out why.  I would just use the OR operator, except I will be passing a list of manufacturers in dynamically.  Any thoughts as to why the first construct is not working?  Better, any thoughts on how to make it work?  Thanks!

Comment: `==` is the wrong operator. Use `%in%`.For example: `subset=manufacturer %in% c("honda","harley")`

Comment: Ah ha!  That did the trick.  So what exactly was == doing?

Comment: Checking values alternately rather than across the entire set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `==` is alternating between the values of "honda" and "harley" and comparing with the value in the relevant position of your "manufacturer" variable. On the other hand, `%in%` (as suggested by MrFlick) and `|` are checking across the entire "manufacturer" variable before deciding which values to mark.

`==` will recycle values to the length of what is being compared.

This might be easier to see with an example:

```
set.seed(1)
v1 <- sample(letters[1:5], 10, TRUE)
v2 <- c("a", "b")   ## Will be recycled to rep(c("a", "b"), 5) when comparing with v1

data.frame(v1, v2, 
           `==` = v1 == v2, 
           `%in%` = v1 %in% v2, 
           `|` = v1 == "a" | v1 == "b", 
           check.names = FALSE)
#    v1 v2    ==  %in%     |
# 1   b  a FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 2   b  b  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# 3   c  a FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 4   e  b FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 5   b  a FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 6   e  b FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 7   e  a FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 8   d  b FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 9   d  a FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 10  a  b FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Notice that in the `==` column, the only `TRUE` value was where "v1" and the recycled values of "v2" were the same.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.  This now makes perfect sense as to why the numbers kept decreasing when I added more manufacturers to the list.